# finding part of text containing specific words using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to do something like (using python):

- check if a word occurs in json file
- find a part of that file with that word, that part needs to start and end with other words

I don't have problem with first point, but second is trouble. I was trying to using regex

```
startWord.+ foundWord +.endingWord
```

but it doesn't work. What is more, I use basic open() function to open json file. But for the program it is seen as single line. What should I do to be able to find just some lines or part of it?

I am rather new in python, hope that question isn't very silly :) Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please show more code. What Regexp have you tried  ? Give us a sample of the text you want to analyze...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the actual occurrence plus some padding, you can simply use `str.index()` to find the beginning index, decide some padding `result_padding = 10` and eventually add up the length of your target string.

```
import re

target_beginning = "hello"
target_string = "asd"
target_ending = "world"

my_regex = "("+target_beginning+".*"+target_string +".*"+target_ending+")"

json_string = "{ someArr: ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is'], a: 'asd', b: 'world'}"

if re.search(my_regex, json_string, re.IGNORECASE):
      #etcetc...
```

I strongly recommend this website for regex learning - [RexExr](https://regexr.com/)

Further reading about the `re` [python library](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: If I get you right, your code finds target_string and prints some symbols that are before and after that string (number of them is defined by padding). But it is not what I am looking for. I need to find part of text beginning with specific word, containing target_string and finishing with specific word. I don't know how long is that part. It can vary depending on json file I want to analyse. I know I can find all three words, I just thought that it is possible to do it simpler.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I will update my answer.